# Read GET value on JavaScript src attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using this code and my file name is ads.js

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*?)[#.]/gi, function(m, key, value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
var pic = getUrlVars()["pic"];
var random_ads_array = ["visitors.jpg", "payouts.jpg", "logos-icon.jpg"];

function getRandomAds(imgAr, path) {
    path = path || 'buycimg/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgAr.length);
    var img = imgAr[num];
    var imgStr = '<a href="http://appricart.com/' + pic + '.html"><img src="' + path + img + '" alt = ""></a>';
    document.write(imgStr);
    document.close();
}
```

And in html part I am using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ads.js?pic=45bus67"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">getRandomAds(random_ads_array);</script>
```

Out put is showing an image but not showing the correct link
Output is like this

> http://appricart.com/undefined.html

I want to show

> http://appricart.com/45bus67.html

Help related this thankx

Comment: You need to read from the URL of your script, not the URL of the document.

Comment: what is the value of `window.location.href` at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just put the pic value into the function?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ads.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">getRandomAds(random_ads_array, "45bus67");</script>
```

ads.js

```
var random_ads_array = ["visitors.jpg", "payouts.jpg", "logos-icon.jpg"];
function getRandomAds(imgAr, pic, path) {
    path = path || 'buycimg/'; // default path here
    var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * imgAr.length );
    var img = imgAr[ num ];
    var imgStr = '<a href="http://appricart.com/' + pic + '.html"><img src="' + path + img + '" alt = ""></a>';
    document.write(imgStr); document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could give it an ID - and then:

```
src = document.getElementById("scriptId").getAttribute("src");
src = src.split("?pic="); 
src = src[1];
```

And voila! You can do what you need to do with `src`